# How to send a DataTable to oracle stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, merge, datatable

I need to pass a DataTable to the Oracle DB stored procedure to merge with an existing table, dynamically, from a c# function.

with Microsoft SQL database it's pretty easy, just create a UDT in the database that can match the DataTable column names and then I can use merge in the procedure.

I need to create the user-defined type dynamically and create a merge script dynamically given only the table name, the columns names and type, and the data.

is there a way to do so with Oracle?

I need to do the same with Microsoft SQL database: creating a dynamic user-defined type, using it with a merge procedure that was dynamically created.

just to be clear. the problem is making those merge dynamically, inside the C#.
I do not want to create a new procedure or a user-definded type inside the Oracle or Microsoft SQL databases.

Comment: By "SQL database", do you mean "Microsoft SQL Server"? SQL is a query language used with many databases, not a product from one particular vendor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# DataTable to Oracle Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890745/c-sharp-datatable-to-oracle-stored-procedure)

Comment: Bob, yes I meant Microsoft SQL server, I edited the question.
ArunPratap it's not helping me much